# Implementing a callback function or execute function when another function returns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions that are executed simultaneously but one needs to be called only when another returns. There is a bit of complexity that goes into how the two functions are called, so unfortunately, I cannot put one of the functions in another function and add a callback.

Here are the two functions:

```
function loadJson = function(json, url, link) {
    /* blackbox function called by a process */
    return json;
}

function onLoad = function () {
    /* do some actions after json is loaded and returned */
}
```

Is there any way to detect that loadJson has returned and only then call the onLoad function?

Comment: Show us that complexity. For sure it is possible to use a callback.

Comment: Do you mean that `loadJSON` is asynchronous? Then you cannot `return json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass the callback to `loadJson` as an argument, and call it before returning:

```
var loadJson = function(json, url, link, callback) {
    //Your mysterious secret and complex function;
    callback(json);
    return json;
}

var onJsonLoaded = function(json) {
    //do some actions
    console.log(json);
}
```

Then, call it like this:

```
loadJson(YOUR, PARAMETERS, HERE, onJsonLoaded);
```

Or you could even inline the callback, saving a variable:

```
loadJson(YOUR, PARAMETERS, HERE, function(json) {
    //do some actions
    console.log(json);
});
```